# MYSQLi-Connection does't work when PHP-Code is included in HTML

Tags: php, mysqli

this is NOT a duplicate of another question.
It's not "how to parse php in html", it's "why php isn't parsed if it's included"

I've a webproject written in PHP, using MYSQL-DB.
Now I try to migrate the project from a websapce (no server-access!) running PHP 7.2 to a webspace running PHP 8.0.13.
The webpages have PHP-Code included but .html-Extension.
It works with .htaccess

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .php
#or (both working)
AddType application/x-httpd-php80 .html .php
```

The problem: MYSQL-Connection only works when the code is directly put into the html-document but it doesn't work if the script is "included".
In Example (sample.html):

```
<html>
<?php 
/* This will work */
$host = "XXX";
$user = "XXX";
$pass = "XXX";
$daba = "XXX";
$SQLI = mysqli_connect(...)
/* This doesn't work */
include "path/xyz/dbconnection.php";
?>
</html>
```

It ends up with the following error-messaging: **Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in...**

Comment: I seriously doubt it works when it is directly in the same file instead of being included

Comment: You can doubt but it works fine

Comment: Show us the contents of "path/xyz/dbconnection.php"

Comment: "why php isn't parsed if it's included" According to your question, the PHP code is parsed always. Please be a little more clear what exactly you think the issue is.